# why pip is not working after removing the metadata and can't be reinstalled by python

Tags: python, pip

**No module named 'pip._internal.metadata**

I have removed meta data from my pc manually and now I got this message:

***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.metadata'***

pip is not functioning now!!

I tried to upgrade through python command:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
however the same error message appear
:

(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.metadata')

Comment: _I have removed meta data from my pc manually_ And why did you do that?

Comment: if `pip` has problem to work then using `pip` to reinstall `pip` makes no sense. You should rather reinstall `Python` or search script `get_pip.py` which downloads and installs module again without using `pip`. See [https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the `ensurepip` module available:

```
$ python -m ensurepip --version
```

Now remove the dist info of the broken `pip` installation. Locate the directory via e.g.

```
$ python -c "import importlib.metadata as m; print(next(f for f in m.files('pip') if f.name == 'METADATA').locate().parent)"
/private/tmp/tst/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip-22.0.4.dist-info
```

You can also invoke the deletion of the dist info directory with a variant of the above command

```
$ python -c "import importlib.metadata as m; import shutil; shutil.rmtree(next(f for f in m.files('pip') if f.name == 'METADATA').locate().parent)"
```

Now reinstall `pip`:

```
$ python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```